# What's an inductive invariant for this piece of code?

Tags: loops, z3, coq, invariants, loop-invariant

For this piece of code:

```
  // n is a user input that can be any integer
  s = 0
  i = 0

  while i < n:
    s = s + 1
    i = i + 1

  return s
```

I would like to prove that the post condition is `if n > 0 then s = sum(0, n) else s = 0` where `sum(s,e)` just adds 1 from `s` to `e` exclusive, starting from initial value of 0.

I thought an invariant is 
`if n > 0 and i < n then s = sum(0, i) else s = 0` but I can't get it to be proven in Coq or z3. Any hints?

Comment: You can't prove that, because it is not true.  For example, for `n=2` your program returns `2`, but `sum(0,2) = 3`.

Comment: changed to exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to imply that this algorithm computes the sum but it doesn't actually do that. Instead, it'll count up to `n`. Perhaps what you intended is:

```
i = 0
s = 0
while i < n:
  i = i+1
  s = s+i
```

Note that we increment `s` by `i`, not by `1` as in your program.

Assuming this is the intended program, then a good invariant would be:

- `s` is the sum of all numbers upto and including `i`
- `i` is at most `n`

In more programmatic notation:

```
s == i*(i+1)/2 && i <= n
```

To see why, remember that the invariant has to hold before and after each loop iteration; and when the loop condition is false, it needs to imply your post-condition. That's why you need the conjunct `i <= n`, so that when you exit the loop, `s` will contain the sum indeed.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry by sum I really do intend to just count up to n but not adding up all the numbers. Also, I don't think your invariant works since if n < 0 then s will be 0.

Comment: If you're just counting up, you obviously don't need two variables. In your program, you can easily prove `i = s` at all times.

Comment: I am trying to express the invariant in terms of my `sum` function.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution:

```
// Function left unimplemented, for simplicity
function sum(s: Int, e: Int): Int
  ensures result == e - s

method foo(n: Int) returns (s: Int)
  requires 0 <= n
{
  var i: Int := 0
  s := 0

  while (i < n)
    invariant s == n - sum(i, n)
  {
    s := s + 1
    i := i + 1
  }
}
```

[Language and tool are called Viper](http://viper.ethz.ch/tutorial/). You can try [your example online](http://viper.ethz.ch/viperonline/tool/silver?key=2020042319026322355382c62f76d50ef135) (the web interface is somewhat slow and unstable), or [use the VSCode plugin](https://www.pm.inf.ethz.ch/research/viper/downloads.html).